# Rotating point using ArcObjects?

Tags: arcobjects, c#

I have a problem to rotate a point (valve symbol) on a polyline I used the code below and it works with me but when I put point on line only and did not work with polyline

```
 public double pointAngle(IPoint aPoint, IFeature LineFeature)
    {
        IPolyline pPolyline = LineFeature.Shape as IPolyline;
        IPoint pFromPoint = pPolyline.FromPoint;
        IPoint pToPoint = pPolyline.ToPoint;

        ILine pLine = new Line();
        pLine.PutCoords(pToPoint, pFromPoint);
        ILine pLine2 = new Line();
        pLine2.PutCoords(aPoint, pFromPoint);
        ILine pLine3 = new Line();
        pLine3.PutCoords(aPoint, pToPoint);
        double dAngle;
        if (pLine3.Length < pLine2.Length)
        {
          //  dAngle = ((pLine3.Angle* 180)/pi); //Math.PI) ;
            dAngle = ((pLine3.Angle * 180) / Math.PI) ;
        }
        else
        {
            dAngle = ((pLine2.Angle* 180)/ Math.PI) ;
        }
        dAngle = dAngle + 90;
        return dAngle;

    }
```

and when I used this code nothing happen with me because I think I use ITransform2D.rotate wrong

```
 IFeature feature = dssClass.SelectFeatureByID("Valve", 180);
        IPoint ppPoint = feature.Shape as IPoint;
        double radian = 1.5708;
        ITransform2D pTrans2D = ppPoint as ITransform2D;
        pTrans2D.Rotate(ppPoint, radian);
```

All I need like this picture

[image]

Comment: I suspect the Transform has worked you need to write the new geometry back to your dataset. As we are not seeing the whole code I can't tell if you are actually storing the feature?

Answer (score 1):

A point geometry has 0 dimension so rotating it will have no effect. As I understand from your question, you want to rotate the symbol - not the feature. The usual approach is to add an attribute to the feature class to store the symbol rotation value. Then apply that field using the Layer-> Properties-> Symbology dialog.

Answer (score 0):

```
        ITransform2D pTrans2D = ppPoint as ITransform2D;
        pTrans2D.Rotate(otherPoint, radian);
```

otherPoint - The point relative to which will be the rotation